# Replace character in column with previous column character in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of snps and their respective proxies.

I want to replace every time there is a "warning" in the proxy column with the character in the previous column, i.e., in the snp column.

so if i have

```
snp        proxy
rs272653   rs235343
rs35775    WARNING
rs726354   rs28635
```

i want:

```
snp        proxy
rs272653   rs235343
rs35775    rs35775
rs726354   rs28635


sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: Can you give a code snipit to attempt the warning replacement? Currently its too broad to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all, thank you all for your answers!

So, my data frame `data` contained the columns "SNP" and "Proxy". These were factors! Because of that i had to first know exactly which SNPs in the "SNP" column had a "WARNING" in the "Proxy" column and then add it to levels in the "Proxy".

```
data[data$Proxy == "WARNING", "SNP"]
#[1] rs11571833 rs17879961 rs12048493 rs72755295 rs9257408


levels(data$Proxy) <- c(levels(data$Proxy), "rs11571833", "rs17879961", "rs12048493", "rs72755295", "rs9257408")
```

Only then would `@code_is_entropy` answer work! Sorry for the trouble!

`data[data$Proxy == "WARNING", "Proxy"] <- data[data$Proxy ==  "WARNING", "SNP", drop = FALSE]`

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Is there something I am missing? If df is your data frame, it should be straight forward.

```
df[df$proxy == "WARNING", "proxy"] <- df[df$proxy == "WARNING", "snp"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it gives me this error:  

`> data[data$Proxy == "WARNING", "Proxy"] <- data[data$Proxy == "WARNING", "SNP"]`  
 
`Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(15L, 42L, 20L, 79L, 89L :  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: So i've been looking into it and what happens is that my data.frame has more than one "WARNING" which is a factor with one level that occurs 5 times. so:  
`j = data[data$Proxy == "WARNING", "Proxy"]`    
`j = droplevels(j)`    
    
`[1] WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING
Levels: WARNING`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use regular expressions (`regexpr`) and a mechanism to replace matches with the other string (`regmatches<-`). Your data:

```
x <- structure(list(snp = c("rs272653", "rs35775", "rs726354"), proxy = c("rs235343", "**WARNING**", "rs28635")), .Names = c("snp", "proxy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

The code. Note that `regmatches<-` is one of the few functions in R that use **side-effect** to make the change: though this call returns (invisibly) the vector fed into it (`x$snp`), it is changing the internal storage of `x$proxy`.

```
regmatches(x$proxy, gregexpr("warning", x$proxy, ignore.case = TRUE)) <- x$snp
x
#        snp       proxy
# 1 rs272653    rs235343
# 2  rs35775 **rs35775**
# 3 rs726354     rs28635
```

Comment: regmaches<-  only functions if the previous column has the same character lenght as "WARNING", i.e, 7. In this case it worked by chance. the rs..... in the snp column does not necessarily have that lenght.

Comment: Show data that shows this code not working, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: `> regmatches(data$Proxy, gregexpr("WARNING", data$Proxy, ignore.case = TRUE))<- data$SNP
Error in (function (u, so, ml)  : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`  

I really appreciate you trying to help me!

Comment: ahhh ... you changed your question after (or "as") I answered, I can adjust.

Comment: I don't get that error (which has nothing to do with the number of characters in a string), so it must be your data. Since you have changed your question "significantly-enough", this answer is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. I suggest either you accept @code_is_entropy's answer or modify your question to suggest why the straight-forward answer does not work for you (*and provide data to trigger the "why"*).